# Adding Where Condition to All Requests EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, predicatebuilder, dynamicquery

Most of my entities **(not all)** have two properties called `CompanyId` and `Deleted`. How would be possible to auto insert these two properties for all select requests instead of setting manually on every single query I have along the whole app.

Example:

```
db.MyEntity.Where(me => me.Id == 1).Select(me => me.Description)
```

- Check dynamically it the entity has the props `CompanyId` and `Deleted`.
- Case affirmative, transform it like this

`db.MyEntity.Where(me => me.Id == 1 && Deleted == false && CompanyId == 1).Select(me => me.Description`)

- Case negative, keep the same select query.

It would help me having to set these conditions to all my queries in which has the properties available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add filter with the help of nuget package: [EntityFramework.Filters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Filters/). Also, good idea is to create common interface instead of dynamically checking for properties existence:

```
public interface IMyEntityInterface
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool Deleted {get;set;}
}

public class MyEntity : IMyEntityInterface
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool Deleted {get;set;}
    //other stuff
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{   
    modelBuilder.Conventions
       .Add(FilterConvention.Create<IMyEntityInterface, int, bool>("MyFilter", (entity, Id, Deleted) => entity.Id == Id && entity.Deleted == Deleted);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var filter = db.EnableFilter("MyFilter");
filter.SetParameter("Id", 1);
filter.SetParameter("Deleted", false);

var data = db.MyEntity.Where(me => me.CompanyId == 1).Select(me => me.Description);
//select Description from MyEntities where Id = 1 and Deleted = false and CompanyId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I chose  [https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/] that is a bit more mature.

Comment: The filter `MyFilter` is global yes, but the filter with `id=1`, and `isDelete=false` is only applicable to the one instance of the query. This is what it seems like from the code above. How can i set the filter values once and for all, in one place ?

Comment: @pnizzle, you can call  `EnableFilter` and set paramaters.at context's constructor.