# Adding where condition to all requests of entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have same problem as in following

[Adding Where Condition to All Requests EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154894/adding-where-condition-to-all-requests-ef6)

but I use Entity Framework core. Is it possible to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **NO**

But it may be possible in the future.

Entity Framework Core doesn't have yet Interceptor which is required to built this kind of feature.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

That is probably the closest you can do at this moment.

The context is filtered but not related entities in Include method (require Interceptor).

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.
var ctx = new EntitiesContext();

ctx.Filter<Post>(q => q.Where(x => !x.IsSoftDeleted));

// SELECT * FROM Post WHERE IsSoftDeleted = false
var list = ctx.Posts.ToList();
```

Wiki: [Query Filter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-filter)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **YES** since EF Core >= 2.0 with [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) :)

Assuming the below entity:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

You can configure a global query filter in OnModelCreating using `HasQueryFilter`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
```

With the above, Posts that have `IsDeleted` set to `true` no longer will be included in the results, unless you explicitly have a `Where` clause for them, or disable global filters in that query:

```
var posts = db.Posts
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .ToList();
```

> Some common applications of this feature are:
>
> **Soft delete** - An Entity Type defines an *IsDeleted* property.
>
> **Multi-tenancy** - An Entity Type defines a *TenantId* property.